# Is it possible to access as3 functions and variables through JSFL?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jsfl

I am writing a JSFL script to export a set of png files for each major section of a flash animation. In order to do this, I need access to functions and variables in the Flash file's Main.as class. The documentation for JSFL is very sparse on the net, and I can't tell if this is possible. Here is what I have:

```
var docs = fl.documents;

for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++)
{
    //loop through everything and turn off compression for max quality
    var libItems = docs[i].library.items;
    for (j = 0; j < libItems.length; j++){
        if(libItems[j].itemType == "bitmap"){
        libItems[j].allowSmoothing = true;
        libItems[j].compressionType = "lossless";
        }
    }
    //the variable adStages is an array of functions in the as3 class
    //this way of trying to access the array doesn't work
    for(k = 0; k<docs[i].adStages.length; k++){
        //here I need to run function adStages[k] to move the animation on
        //to the next frame to capture
        docs[i].exportPNG("file:///Users/Graeme/Desktop/"+ docs[i].name + k,true, true);
    }

}
```

I know I can do this a more clunky way by extending the Main.as file and using as3corelib PNGEncoder to export the files but I feel if this way works it could be more elegant and I don't have to be prompted on where to put the files each frame.

Comment: there used to be an actionscript property with which you could write or read the actionscript as a string in a frame but this has been removed in latest versions. Still this was not even close to wjat you want to do which is not possible via jsfl.

Comment: I noticed a lot of threads on ExternalInterface relating to JSFL. I take it I can't use ExternalInterface to call functions in a SWF I'm testing to increment the current section and return false when it's done?

Comment: There are JSFL functions that are specifically for going to the next frame. Flash CC also has code that is designed to automate exporting existing frame-based animations as sprites. Can you be more specific about what you want? I don't see anything in your question that says you "need" to have access to the functions (which you couldn't run even if you could get hold of them).

Comment: Next frame is no good I'm afraid. Essentially I'm making flash banner ads and backup gif for when the flash ad doesn't get served. Hence the exporting of a snapshot of each stage of animation. I don't make banner ads on the timeline as it would take too long to edit each unique size, so instead I use TweenLite and divide the ad into stages so it can be easily broken down into gif frames. What I stated in my question and in the code comments that what I need is a way of running an as3 function, plus access to the adStages array in as3. JSFL docs were not clear as to whether it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed swf file into [custom Flash IDE panel](http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2011/03/10/creating-flash-extensions-pt-5-swf-panels/) and then communicate through external interface or call JSFL code directly from AS3 via MMExecute() method. If plant to do lots of work with JSFL then consider reading [Keith Peter's book Extending FlashMX 2004](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Extending-Flash-2004-Reference-JavaScript/dp/1590593049/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412953387&sr=8-1&keywords=extending%20flash). this book is old but still very good and not outdated.